# xUnit + Gallio + code coverage in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, code-coverage, gallio, xunit.net

I'm trying to find a way to migrate from mstest to xunit and still benefit from the IDE integration which made me choose mstest in the first place. Gallio seems to accomplish this noble goal, plus it's free (don't want Reshaper or TestDriven.net). But I can't get code coverage to work.

My solution contains of two projects: project SUT (the assembly I need to test) and project SUT.Tests which is a VS test project (this allows Gallio to display xunit tests in VS's Test View). I have code coverage enabled in Local.testSettings for SUT.dll and instrumentation is in place. After the test run completes there is no code coverage. Code Coverage Results window reports: *Empty results generated: none of the instrumented binary was used. Look at test run details for any instrumentation problems.* Unfortunately the test run details do not contain any "instrumentation problems". I tried unchecking the *instrument assemblies in place* checkbox and re-running the unit test; same result.

Any idea what's wrong?

My setup:
- Windows 7 x64
- VS 2010 Premium (SP1)
- xUnit 1.8
- Gallio 3.3.1 x64 (installer, not zip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question:

Turns out Gallio loads SUT.dll from SUT.Tests\Bin\Debug rather than SUT\Bin\Debug. I added this path to code coverage details, selected it instead of the default SUT.dll path and now it works! This is better described at [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2010/03/06/nunitforvs-integrating-nunit-tests-into-visual-studio.aspx), towards the end of the post.

Comment: don't be sorry for your answering your own question. Its appreciated that you are self learner. +1 for your self learning